# while loop with unsigned integer condition

Tags: c++

I'm not sure how the while loop works in the following simple piece of code

```
short CountBits(unsigned int x){
    short num_bits = 0;
    while (x){
        num_bits += x & 1;
        x >>= 1;
    }
    return num_bits;
}
```

How does an unsigned integer evaluate to True or False?

Answer (score 5):

In the given context, `x` must be converted to `true` or `false`.

From the C++11 Standard (4.12/1):

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`.

Think of

```
while (x){ ... }
```

as

```
while (x != 0){ ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

True is any integer which is not equal to 0. Thus if x evaluates to 0 then the loop breaks.

Answer (score 2):

"How does an unsigned integer evaluate to True or False"? The same way **any** numeric value evaluates to `true` or `false`: 0 is `false`, any other value is `true`. Some people would write the test as `while (x != 0)`; that's exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

For any integral number in C++, on most machines, 0 will evaluate to false. As such, when X becomes 0, the loop will terminate. The loop will continue while x is a non-zero value.

Comment: Tell us more about those machines where the loop doesn't terminate when `x` becomes `0`

Comment: C++ has a standard, it specifies that x being 0 does make the loop terminate